# MS word page numbers format: i, ii, ..., 1, 2,

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers

I have a MS word document that I want have the following page numbers for in the header:

- page 1: no page number (title page)
- pages 2-5: i, ii, iii, iv
- pages 6 and onward:
  1, 2, 3, ...

This seems like such a simple task, but everywhere I look I'm being given advice for previous versions of word that are clearly quite different.

I'm using version 2111.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> everywhere I look I'm being given advice for previous versions of word
> that are clearly quite different

***All versions of Word, at least from Word 97 on, handle this the same way, with a Section break and using the Format Page Number dialog.***

### The best exposition on the topic, of which I am aware, is by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill: [Numbering Front Matter](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/FrontMatterRibbon.htm).

*Paraphrasing:*

1. Separate the main document from the front matter using a Next-Page or Odd-Page **Section Break**.
2. Insert Page Numbering in the Main Section

- Tell it to begin at 1 in the section
- If necessary format the page number

3. Insert page numbering in the front matter and format as lower-case Roman numerals

In your case, you could tell the beginning section to begin at 0 and use the [Different-First-Page](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Different_First_Page) switch for your header and footer to not have a page number in your cover page.

*Note that if additional sections are added later, they will restart numbering unless you tell Word, in that section, to use continuous numbering. Word uses whatever the setting in the current section is for the new section.*

Additional references on my website:

- [Page Numbers in Word 2007-2021 (365)](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers)
- [Pagination Fields](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination)

The link above about the Different-First Page setting is also to my website.